# Settings - Could not load file or assembly System 4.0.0.0

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, .net-3.5, settings, .net-assembly

I use `.net 3.5` for my class library project.

I create a `Settings` file and with a boolean value , and I change its value on button click:

The Settings value is changed and saved properly, but I get the following error:

```
Could not load file or assembly   
'System, Version 4.0.0.0, Culture= neutral, PublicKeyToken...'
```

**What I've tried:**

I checked the`System` reference properties. Its version is 2.0.0.0.

I also changed the `app.config` file so that the group of `userSettings` will contain `Version=2.0.0.0` instead of `Version=4.0.0.0`

What is missing?

Comment: Try changing the target framework to `4.0.0.0`

Comment: @Rahul, Thanks. I cannot. I use references that requires .net 3.5. Any ideas?

Comment: .resx files are the other ones that can have the wrong version.